# Hyphen for phrases using names without hyphen

Tags: hyphen

- Viele Bahncard 100 Besitzer finden, dass...
- Viele Bahncard 100 - Besitzer finden, dass...
- Viele "Bahncard 100"-Besitzer finden, dass...
- Viele Bahncard-100-Besitzer finden, dass...

The ticket-name is "Bahncard 100". Then how do I form longer phrases from it correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a question that very commonly arises when streets, buildings or other geographical objects are named after people in the German-speaking countries. For example, the square named after Ernst Reuter is spelled [Ernst-Reuter-Platz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst-Reuter-Platz).

So your last variant (Bahncard-100-Besitzer) is definitely good.

I think the variant with quotation marks ("Bahncard 100"-Besitzer) is also acceptable, the quotation marks make it clear what belongs together. The other two variants are not good, especially not the first one, that is a fairly blatant [Deppenleerzeichen](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/).

Comment: Not sure I fully agree. Yes, in street names "hyphens everywhere" has become the rule in recent years, but I still encounter things like "Dr. Hugo Wolff-Weg" etc. on a daily basis. Not sure what happened to my initial comment, but I still think rewording the phrase ("Besitzer einer Bahncard 100") might be the best option.

Comment: @Ingmar Just because you encounter it doesn't mean it's correct spelling. That may once have been, but definitely isn't anymore, "Dr.-Hugo-Wolff-Weg" is how it should be written. Starting point for further research: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung

Comment: All I'm saying is it's definitely (still) out there… But hey, according to the horse's mouth, it's "BahnCard 100-Besitzer:in" anyway: https://www.bahn.de/faq/kann-ich-als-bahncard-100-besitzer-den-komfort-check-in-nutzen

Comment: @Ingmar: literally the last one to ask about this is an online copy editor for a corporation.

Comment: That link, obviously, was provided tongue-in-cheek (sic) …

Comment: Accepted this answer because it mentions both methods that are correct, while Björn Friedrich's answer only mentiones connecting the words with hyphens.

Comment: One more option that arguably corresponds with correct spelling while also making clear what belongs together is the use of some spacing: "Bahncard-100 - Besitzer", "Dr.-Hugo-Wolff - Weg"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper nobody does that

Comment: @wonderbear: If you say so. It seems fairly common to me in somewhat informal, yet technically oriented chats, but maybe it's context-related.

Answer (score 7):

**German:**

Bei *BahnCard 100* handelt es sich um einen Eigennamen. (Man beachte das große *C* in der Mitte.) Hier soll er als erster Bestandteil einer Zusammensetzung mit *Besitzer* verwendet werden, weshalb [§ 50 des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6160#par50) zum Zuge kommt:

> **§ 50**
>
> Man setzt einen Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen, deren erste Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen.

Da es zu dieser Regel keine Erweiterung gibt, die die Regel unter bestimmten Bedingungen relativieren könnte, ist demnach nur richtig:

> Viele *BahnCard-100-Besitzer* finden, dass …

---

**English:**

*BahnCard 100* is a proper name. (Note the capital *C* in the middle.) Here it is to be used as the first component of a compound with *Besitzer*, which is why [§ 50 of the official rules](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6160#par50) comes into play:

> **§ 50**
>
> One puts a hyphen between all components of multi-part compositions whose first components consist of proper names.
>
> <sub>(Translation by myself.)</sub>

Since there is no extension to this rule that could relativize the rule under certain conditions, it is only correct to write:

> Viele *BahnCard-100-Besitzer* finden, dass …

Comment: The official rules have the following caveat: *Die Schreibung mit Bindestrich bei Eigennamen entspricht nicht immer den folgenden Regeln, so dass nur allgemeine Hinweise gegeben werden können.* Therefore, they do not exclude *Bahncard 100-Besitzer*.

Comment: @DavidVogt, you skipped the sentence that follows and that explains where this may be the case: *"Zusammensetzungen aus Eigennamen und Substantiv zur Benennung von Schulen, Universitäten, Betrieben, Firmen und ähnlichen Institutionen werden so geschrieben, wie sie amtlich festgelegt sind. In Zweifelsfällen sollte man nach § 46 bis § 52 schreiben."* This does not apply to *BahnCard-100-Besitzer*.

Comment: Nach dem Lesen der zitierten Stellen bin ich mir nun überhaupt nicht mehr sicher, ob "demnach [tatsächlich] nur [BahnCard-100-Besitzer] richtig" ist: Also: "BahnCard 100" ist ein Eigenname. "Man setzt einen Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen." Was ein "Bestandteil" ist, wird nicht klar definiert, aber es steht zumindest da, dass Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen können, nicht andersherum. Der erste Bestandteil des betrachteten Begriffs wäre demnach "BahnCard 100" und der zweite "Besitzer". Zwischen diese zwei Bestandteile wird ein Bindestrich ...

Comment: ... gesetzt, also "BahnCard 100-Besitzer" ... zumindest, wenn ich mich genau nach den oben zitierten Regeln richte.

Comment: Davon abgesehen stellt sich mir die Frage, wieso die ganzen Regeln denn ausgerechnet nur dann gelten sollten, wenn die _ersten_ Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen. Wieso sollten für "BahnCard-100-Besitzer" (angenommen, dies _ist_ die richtige Schreibweise) gänzlich andere Regeln gelten als für "Nicht-BahnCard-100-Besitzer" oder "Ex-BahnCard-100-Besitzer"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, einfach die Beispiele zu § 50 anschauen. Dort sind *ausnahmslos alle* mehrteiligen Eigennamen durchgekoppelt. Im vorhergehenden § 49 wird sogar explizit von *mehrteiligen Eigennamen* gesprochen. Kurzum, in § 50 ist mit *Bestandteil* auch ein Teil eines mehrteiligen Eigennamens gemeint. Was die Beschränkung auf die ersten Bestandteile betrifft: Warum das so ist, musst du den Rechtschreiberat fragen. Aus Analogiegründen würde ich auch bei den anderen Beispielen (z. B. *Nicht-BahnCard-100-Besitzer*) durchkoppeln.

Answer (score -2):

Contrary to @Wonderbear I argue for *Bahncard 100 Besitzer – the Deppenleerzeichen – because English practice shows that it can work and there is no argument in using slurs.

There is nothing stupendous about it, if one accepts that there is no being stupid about *Bahncard 100*.

Otherwise, the quotation mark variant is a typographical atrocity but clear to the point of marked rejection of that kind of spaced spelling. Note that quotation-marks are by decree to be set alternating low high: *„Bahncard 100“*

---

Alternatively, the longer wording »*Besitzer des Farhscheins „Bahnkarte Einhundert“ (im Folgenden* FS*)*« is prefered for use in legal documents though impossible to italicize in stackexchange markdown.

Comment: Nonsense, you accept a-priori that *Bahncard 100* is de facto the norm. Downvoting as if you were compeled by law despite my acknowledging that other options exist is anal retentive.

Comment: yeah no, I did and I still do